# How do I access session data in the ServiceRunner OnBeforeExecute() method?

Tags: servicestack

I need to be able to access the session ID and other session data in the `OnBeforeExecute()` override in my custom `ServiceRunner` class like this:

```cs
public class MyServiceRunner<T> : ServiceRunner<T>
{
    public override void OnBeforeExecute(IRequestContext requestContext, T request)
    {
        // How to get the session ID?
        // var sessionID = ??

        base.OnBeforeExecute(requestContext, request);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class MyServiceRunner<T> : ServiceRunner<T>
{
    public override void OnBeforeExecute(IRequestContext requestContext, T dto)
    {
        // How to get the session ID?
        var sessionID = requestContext.Get<IHttpRequest>().GetSessionId();

        base.OnBeforeExecute(requestContext, request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response mythz!

Comment: By the way, I realized that I didn't include `using ServiceStack.ServiceInterface;`, that's why initially I couldn't get to `GetSessionId()`.